# I don't see how Cauchy's proof of AM $\ge$ GM holds for all cases?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am reading Maxima and Minima Without Calculus by Ivan Niven and on pages $24-26$ he gives Cauchy's proof for the $AM-GM$ . The general idea of the proof is that $P_{n}$ is the proposition $$(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot a_{n}) \ge n(a_{1} a_{2} \cdot \cdot \cdot  a_{n})^{1/n}$$

The proof proves that if $P_{n}$ holds, then $P_{n-1}$ and $P_{2n}$ also hold. I have a problem with the part that shows that $P_{n-1}$ holds. It goes something like this:

$g$ is the geometric mean of $a_{1} , a_{2} , \cdot \cdot \cdot a_{n-1}$ so that $g=(a_{1} , a_{2} , \cdot \cdot \cdot a_{n-1})^{1/n-1}$

Replace $a_{n}$ with $g$:

$( a_{1}+ a_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot +a_{n-1}+ g) \ge n ( a_{1} a_{2} \cdot \cdot \cdot  g)^{1/n}$

The $RHS$ becomes $n(g^{n-1} g)^{1/n}=ng$

So we have $( a_{1}+ a_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot +a_{n-1}+ g) \ge ng$ , or $( a_{1}+ a_{2}+ \cdot \cdot \cdot +a_{n-1}) \ge (n-1) g$ , therefore if $P_{n}$ holds, then $P_{n-1}$ does also.

I understand the logic of the proof, but the problem I have is when he replaced $a_{n}$ with $g$ . Obviously, the last term is not necessarily equal to the the geometric mean of the rest of the terms. So how does this proof work for all cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The last term is not **necessarily** equal to the geometric mean of the rest that's right , but we are free to choose any term $a_i$ as long as $a_i >0$. Hence for this proof we **set** $g:=a_n$ in order to peform induction. Then we start our induction with $n=2$ wich folows from the well known ineuqality $(x-y)^2\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2 \geq 2xy$. So for $n=2$ the inequality holds.

Then your book proofs: If it is valid for $n$ it is valid for $n-1$ hence the $AM-GM$ inequality is valid for $n=1$. Then it proofs ( wich you didn't post) that if it is valid for $n$ it is valid for $2n$ .

So it is valid for $n:=2$ , $n-1=1$ , $2n=4$. Now set $n:=4$ and it will be valid for $n-1=3$. Set $n:=3$ and it will be valid for $2n=6$ and so on.. You can see that we will cover all natural numbers like that.

Comment: why do we set g:=an? what if g is not equal to an

Answer (score 1):

We wish to show that the case of the inequality with $n$ non-negative numbers proves the case with $n-1$ numbers. Take any $n-1$ non-negative numbers. We may put any non-negative number for $a_n$ since we already know it to be true in the case of $n$ numbers. We simply choose $a_n=g$ where $g$ is as you defined it.

Comment: I don't see how this works; by adding another number to the $n-1$ case you reach the $n$ case, but how does that necessarily prove that the $n-1$ case was correct?

Comment: Because $a_1,...a_{n-1}$ were completely arbitrary since no assumptions (apart from non-negativity which is necessary) were made.

Comment: But still you are supposed to start from the true statement (supposedly true) of $P_n$ and arrive at the statement $P_{n-1}$ by manipulating $P_n$ . The way I see this proof is it saying: "If $P_n$ is true and $a_n=g$, then $P_{n-1}$ is true". But I don't see it saying "If $a_n \not = g$ , then $P_{n-1}$ holds."

Comment: I take it that $P_n$ denotes the statement "The AM-GM inequality holds with all choices of n-tuples of non-negative numbers". We intend to show $P_n\implies P_{n-1}$. Denote the statement of taking $n-1$ arbitrary non-negative numbers, $a_1,...a_{n-1}$, and $a_n=g$ by $Q_n$. We may assume the AM-GM inequality for these choices since the truth of $P_n$ implies the truth of $Q_n$. That is $P_n\implies Q_n$. From here we know that $Q_n\implies P_{n-1}$. By transitivity of implication we have that $P_n\implies P_{n-1}$